# javascript how do i use the hover element on a div-element using a script with namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, hover

In this code i change the color of my div while hovering the mouse over it. How can i achieve this without using style and instead put it in a script with namespace?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
.link-container {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}

.link-container a {
    display: block;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.link-container a:hover {
    background: red;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="link-container">
    <a>hover to  change color</a>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mouseover` event of the element.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('link-container'),function(e){

    e.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        this.style.background='red'
    });

});
```

EDIT:
You need `mouseout` event to remove the applied style.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('link-container'),function(e){

    e.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        this.style.background='red'
    });

    e.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        this.style.background='inherit'
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add eventListeners and have then fire functions in your namespace (say myApp)

```
var myApp = {
  hover: function(event){
    event.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;")
  },
  out: function(event){
    event.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color:green;")
  }

}

var item = document.getElementById("btn");
item.addEventListener("mouseover", myApp.hover, false);
item.addEventListener("mouseout", myApp.out, false);
```

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VlKPgGdQL0CktibI4vnY?p=preview)